# How to debug TCP recv()

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, recv, errno

I have a `client - server - server socket` simulation with bidirectional communication.

My line

```
recv(fd3, serv3_buf, BUFSIZE - 1, 0);
```

returns `-1`

How can you debug `recv` using `errno.h`?

Comment: `linux/Mac Terminal` using `gcc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the man(ual) explanation of error relevants to recv!

> ERRORS
>          These are some standard errors generated by the  socket  layer.   Addi‐
>          tional  errors may be generated and returned from the underlying proto‐
>          col modules; see their manual pages.
>
> ```
>    EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK
>           The socket is marked nonblocking and the receive operation would
>           block, or a receive timeout had been set and the timeout expired
>           before data was received.  POSIX.1-2001 allows either  error  to
>           be  returned for this case, and does not require these constants
>           to have the same value, so a portable application  should  check
>           for both possibilities.
>
>    EBADF  The argument sockfd is an invalid descriptor.
>
>    ECONNREFUSED
>           A remote host refused to allow the network connection (typically
>           because it is not running the requested service).
>
>    EFAULT The  receive  buffer  pointer(s)  point  outside  the  process's
>           address space.
>
>    EINTR  The  receive  was interrupted by delivery of a signal before any
>           data were available; see signal(7).
>
>    EINVAL Invalid argument passed.
>
>    ENOMEM Could not allocate memory for recvmsg().
>
>    ENOTCONN
>           The socket is associated with a connection-oriented protocol and
>           has not been connected (see connect(2) and accept(2)).
>
>    ENOTSOCK
>           The argument sockfd does not refer to a socket.
> ```

You may use perror() and strerror() to manage an error string when recv returns -1.

See the relevant man(ual) for explanation:

[perror](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?perror%203)

[strerror](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?strerror%203)

Comment: Thanks. I had seen this information on search, but i was unsure how to incorporate getting these errors to be displayed

Comment: I got the error back with perror `Socket operation on non-socket`. I will investigate this further.

Comment: I think this means that fd3 (referring to your codeline here in the post) contians a non-valid socket value or initialization! You have to verify if the socket() function that generates it didn't return -1. If -1 is returned when you call the socket() function you have to verify the errno etc, etc. –